# How make JOIN table in ClickHouse DB faster?

Tags: clickhouse

I have two tables

event

- id
- os

params

- id
- sx
- sy

This table have relation 1-1 by id. If execute query

```
select count(*)
from
(select id from event where os like 'Android%')
inner join
(select id from params where sx >= 1024)
using id
```

they very slow

But if all data contains in one table

```
select count(*) from event where sx >= 1024 and os like 'Android%'
```

Query executed very fast.

Please, tell me how use join in ClickHouse DB effective? Keep all data in one table is not convenient.

Answer (score 5):

I experience same problems with joining 2 huge distributed tables.
There are 2 main problems

- durion of executing
- limits by needed memory for a query.

What works for me is sharding calculation query by id%N  using subqueries and union all results then.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM event
    WHERE id%2=0 AND id IN
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM params
        WHERE id % 2 = 0 AND sx >= 1024
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    FROM event
    WHERE id % 2 = 1 AND id IN
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM params
        WHERE id % 2 = 1 AND sx >= 1024
    )
)
```

You can change id%N(2 in the example) until you get needed performance.
Need to replace IN to GLOBAL IN if you use distributed engines for tables.

Answer (score 3):

You may rewrite query like this:

```
select count(*)
from event 
where os like 'Android%' 
AND id IN (select id from params where sx >= 1024)
```

Comment: If all data in one table - 16 sec, if i use sub query - 78 seconds